# DOS command to allocate memory?

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I am trying to run a batch file, written for [DOSbox](http://www.dosbox.com/) in windows 7, in XP command prompt. The DOSbox has a command called `loadfix`, I couldn't find the equivalent for command prompt.

[Loadfix](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/LOADFIX)

Anybody know a DOS command or commands for this purpose?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOS command is `loadfix`, as you already know. It's a command which ONLY makes sense in DOS, as it doesn't affect the batch file at all. It affects the next DOS program started by that batch file.

In comparison, CMD.EXE doesn't start DOS programs, it starts Win32 programs. There simply isn't anything to " loadfix".

Comment: The reason I asked the question is I go the following error message when I run my `line.cmd` "Memory allocation error, Cannot load COMMAND, system halted". Apparently, this does happen in DOSBOX, but If enter `loadfix` -120 before run `line.cmd` then no error.

Comment: Run your DOS programs in DOSBox. That's why DOSBox exists.